# Hide a fixed logo beneath a scrolling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a design to build that calls for a fixed-position logo and a nav bar that scrolls with the page. As the nav bar goes over the logo, the logo begins to hide.  I have spent a lot of time on this and it's quirky at best. Wanted to throw this out to see if maybe there's a simpler solution that I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give the code that is giving you the issue?

Comment: Don't deface your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

That's may be because of your `logo's z-index` issue. If you can increase `z-index` for your logo it will stay on top always. For example if there is logo class with `.logo` your code will look like.

```
.logo { z-index: 99999 }
```

You can use that value according to your own needs, hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If logo has a fixed position (or if it got a `position` value in CSS), you can play with the `z-index` values for putting it above or below some elements.